# How to split a string based on capitalized initials

Tags: openrefine

I was asked how to split a string like "Abc def GhI   jKl MNO  Pqr" into ["Abc def";"Ghi jKl";"MNO Pqr"]
A collegue found a solution in Python, and me this solution in GREL. It seems to work properly, but I am not sure to understand myself the regex ;-)

> value.find(/(\b\p{Lu}[^\s]*(\s+[^\p{Lu}][^\s]*)*)/)

Is there a simpler solution?

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind the split?  Based on the regex it doesn't seem to something simple as splitting at each second space.

Comment: Your regex produces [ "Ab", "Gh", "MN", "Pq" ]. This is not the expected result according to your example. Here is a [visual simulation](https://regexper.com/#%28%5Cb%5BA-Z%5D%5B%5E%5Cs%5D%28%5Cs%2B%5B%5EA-Z%5D%5B%5E%5Cs%5D%29*%29) of your automata.

Comment: Very nice tool! I forgot 2 stars, I believe
    value.find(/(\b\p{Lu}[^\s]*(\s+[^\p{Lu}][^\s]*)*)/)